# Iphone: UIAlertView works in simulator but makes the app freeze on iphone

Tags: iphone, uialertview

I`m working on a project where an alert should pop up after returning from a controller with an empty value. It does pop up in the simulator, but on the iphone the app freeze and exit when returning from the controller. Any ideas?

Here is my code:

```
  - (void)manualBarcodeViewControllerDidFinish:(ManualBarcodeViewController *)controller
    {

        ......
        ......

        else if([barcode isEqualToString:@""])
        {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"error" message:@"message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"otherbutton"];
            [alert show];
        [alert release];
         }
     }
```

Comment: What's the stack trace when the application crashes?

Comment: Open the Xcode Organizer when the iPhone is connected - that will show you the available crash dumps for your application.  Then you can post the stack trace to help us diagnose the problem.

Comment: ah.. nice, didn`t know that :) still very new to xcode...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `otherButtonTitles` argument needs to be nil-terminated.

In general, methods that take a variable number of arguments, need to have nil at the end. For example:

```
[NSArray arrayWithObjects:objA, objB, nil];
```

and in your case:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"error" message:@"message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"otherbutton", nil];
```

Answer (score 2):

you should look at this question maybe it will help:

[uialertview causes crash in release mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501158/uialertview-causes-crash-in-release-mode)